# PowerShell Inheritance False

Tags: powershell, acl

Trying to only show the folders that IsInherited is False

**My Code**

```
$folder = "C:\TZTEST"
$aclentry = get-childitem $folder -recurse -force | get-acl | % {$_.Access}
$manypaths = get-childitem $folder -recurse -force
$aclentry | Format-Table

$newlist = @()

foreach($onepath in $manypaths) {
$acldata=$(get-childitem $folder -recurse -force | get-acl | % {$_.Access})
$itemobject = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
    if ($onepath.Mode -match "d-----" -and $acldata.IsInherited -eq $false -and $acldata.PropagationFlags -eq "InheritOnly") {
        $itemobject | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name "Location" -Value $onepath.FullName
        $itemobject | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name "IsInherited" -Value $acldata.IsInherited
        $newlist +=$itemobject
        }
}
$newlist
```

**Works partially**
When all folders inheriting permissions under the targeted folder gives no output (correct)
When one or more folders are not inheriting permissions the output shows all folders under the targeted folder(incorrect)

**Folder Setup**
Targeted Folder
|-Subfolder1 - Subfolder3
|-Subfolder2

Inheritance enabled on 2 of the 3 subfolders (Subfolder1, Subfolder2 *enabled*) (Subfolder3 *disabled*) (incorrect output)
[Folder Permission - Subfolder3 No Inherit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjbLt.png)

Inheritance enabled on all subfolders (correct output)
[Folder Permission - All Inherit (no output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaxLg.png)

**My Question**
Is there some way to make only the folder that does not have inheritance enabled show in my output?

Thanks in advance for any help or insight you can provide.

Comment: `$newlist |? IsInherited -eq $False` ?

Comment: You're getting the ACL for every file and folder inside your root folder once for each file and folder in the root folder... if you have 5 files and folders you're getting the ACLs 25 times. Get them once, check if any access rights are inherited, pass through those that have no inherited rights: `gci $folder\* -Directory|? {$true -notin (Get-ACL $_).Access.IsInherited}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want the output from folders where 'IsInherited' on all Access Control Entries is false. With that in mind, we just need to evaluate them as to whether they contain $true.

I have set a folder path up similar to your example and disabled inheritance on the bottom directory.

`C:\Test\Test\NoInherit`

```bsh
Get-ChildItem C:\Test -Recurse | 
? { $_.Attributes -eq [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Directory } | 
? { ((Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).GetAccessRules($true,$true,[System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).IsInherited -notcontains $true) -eq $true }
```

Comment: That worked, it is giving me to correct output, now to get it formatted for the net part.

Thanks again